# What is the best way to save data for a table within a table?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, save, master-detail

I have gone through the tutorial on apple's developer website called 'Your Second iOS Application' in which I learned how to make my master detail application. I went on to learn how to save the data of the master and detail view controllers with sqlite3. Now I want to add another table view controller and view controller structured the same way as the Master Detail application but within the Master Detail structure I have already created. And within each cell the user creates, I would like for it to show different data than if you were to navigate through a different cell.

Basically, I am wondering what the best and/or simplest way to save this is.
Please ask questions if you need it.

Comment: If you have already implemented the master-detail application where are you facing problems?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the data you can use core-data. First create the model for this. (Create the relations if necessary). Then create and add objects to the context and save the context. Here you don't have to worry about how its saved (default is sqlite in iOS). If you need to get started with core-data check this out: [Raywanderlich - core data](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started).